# How to activate spell checker inside Pycharm, it stop working

Tags: pycharm

My spell checker stopped working all of sudden. It is not correcting my misspelled English words.

I have activated and deactivated spell checking inside Pycharm preferences, but no luck at all.

Comment: Do you have bundled dictionaries enabled in **Settings | Editor | Spelling**?

Comment: yes, I do have that!